# show abbreviated timezone name from datetimeoffset field in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2017

I need to show abbreviated timezone name from datetimeoffset field in SSRS. E.g.

| Value In Database | Expected Output |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-13 8:00 +5:30 | 2021-01-13 8:00 IST |
| 2021-01-13 23:00 -6:00 | 2021-01-13 23:00 CST |

What's the best practice to achieve same? There is no direct way to do same.

Though I need to ultimately show this in SSRS but could there be a tSQL only solution?

One of the solution I can think is to create a table like -

| OffsetValue | ShortTimeZone | LongTimeZone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| +5:30 | IST | Indian Standard Time |
| -8:00 | PST | Pacific Standard Time |
| -6:00 | CST | Central Time Zone |

TIA!

Comment: Yes, that is the best solution... But the first column must be in minute (smallint)

Comment: Agreed. You might want to also look at this which has some useful timezone related stuff for sql server https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport